# How to add the filename of the source file to the first cell of every row using TransferSpreadsheet?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to add the filename of the source excel file to the first cell of each line imported to an Access table.

I searched the web but was not able to find a close example of what I wanted to achieve.

```vb
Public Function Import()
Dim path As String
Dim fileName As String
path = "C:\Users\" & NetworkUser() & "\Documents\TestDatabase\"
fileName = Dir(path & "\*.xlsx")
While fileName <> ""
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Table1", path & fileName, True, "A4:S28"
fileName = Dir()
Wend
Call DeleteEmptyRows
End Function
```

an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

Input from Excel files

```
Stone | 5 | No
Door | 1 | No
```

```
Table | 2 | No
Chair | 6 | No
```

```
Fuel | 12 | Yes
```

Output on Access table

```
example1.xlsx | Stone | 5 | No
example1.xlsx | Door | 1 | No
example2.xlsx | Table | 2 | No
example2.xlsx | Chair | 6 | No
example3.xlsx | Fuel | 12 | Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the spreadsheet into an existing table which contains a `filename` text-valued field, and then run a simple `update` query to populate the `filename` field with the filename of the spreadsheet.

For example, assuming that your table `Table1` contains an additional field called `filename`, you could run an `update` query after the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method:

```
While fileName <> ""
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Table1", path & fileName, True, "A4:S28"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "update table1 set table1.filename = '" & fileName & "' where table1.filename is null"
    fileName = Dir()
Wend
```